# My Node JS App deployed by IIS NODE, from LAN it is not accessible

Tags: node.js, express, web, url-rewriting, iisnode

1. My Node App is works fine on localhost but when I try to access from LAN it is not Accessible.
2. This app is hosted by iisnode module.
3. To Access in local host I have add "IP site.name" in windows Hosts file.
4. The web.config file I have shared. My system is runs on windows 10.**
   Please Replay me if someone is familiar with this fault.

   `process.env.<key>
       -->

      <!-- Unconmment the below appSetting if you'd like to use a Virtual Directory -->
      <!-- <add key="virtualDirPath" value="" /> -->
   </appSettings>
   <system.webServer>
       <!-- Remove the modules element if running on IIS 8.5-->
       <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="false"/>

       <iisnode node_env="%node_env%"
                nodeProcessCountPerApplication="1"
                maxConcurrentRequestsPerProcess="1024"
                maxNamedPipeConnectionRetry="100"
                namedPipeConnectionRetryDelay="250"
                maxNamedPipeConnectionPoolSize="512"
                maxNamedPipePooledConnectionAge="30000"
                asyncCompletionThreadCount="0"
                initialRequestBufferSize="4096"
                maxRequestBufferSize="65536"
                uncFileChangesPollingInterval="5000"
                gracefulShutdownTimeout="60000"
                loggingEnabled="true"
                logDirectory="iisnode"
                debuggingEnabled="true"
                debugHeaderEnabled="false"
                debuggerPortRange="5058-6058"
                debuggerPathSegment="debug"
                maxLogFileSizeInKB="128"
                maxTotalLogFileSizeInKB="1024"
                maxLogFiles="20"
                devErrorsEnabled="true"
                flushResponse="false"
                enableXFF="false"
                promoteServerVars=""
                configOverrides="iisnode.yml"
                watchedFiles="web.config;*.js"
                nodeProcessCommandLine="C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe"/>

       <!-- 
           Before the handlers element can work on IIS 8.5
           follow steps listed here https://github.com/tjanczuk/iisnode/issues/52 
       -->                 
       <handlers>
           <add name="iisnode" path="index.js" verb="*" modules="iisnode"/>

           <!-- Uncomment below handler if using Socket.io -->
           <!--<add name="iisnode-socketio" path="index.js" verb="*" modules="iisnode" />-->
       </handlers>

       <rewrite>
           <rules>
               <!-- Don't interfere with requests for node-inspector debugging -->
               <rule name="NodeInspector" patternSyntax="ECMAScript" stopProcessing="true">
                   <match url="^index.js\/debug[\/]?"/>
               </rule>

               <!-- First we consider whether the incoming URL matches a physical file in the /public folder -->
               <rule name="StaticContent" patternSyntax="Wildcard">
                   <action type="Rewrite" url="public/{R:0}" logRewrittenUrl="true"/>
                   <conditions>
                       <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true"/>
                   </conditions>
                   <match url="*.*"/>
               </rule>

               <!-- All other URLs are mapped to the Node.js application entry point -->
               <rule name="DynamicContent">
                   <conditions>
                       <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="True"/>
                   </conditions>
                   <action type="Rewrite" url="index.js"/>
               </rule>
               <rule name="SocketIO" patternSyntax="ECMAScript">
                   <match url="socket.io.+"/>
                   <action type="Rewrite" url="index.js"/>
               </rule>
           </rules>
       </rewrite>
       <directoryBrowse enabled="false"/>
       <security>
      <requestFiltering>
        <hiddenSegments>
          <add segment="node_modules" />
        </hiddenSegments>
      </requestFiltering>
    </security>
   </system.webServer>`